# Highlight the current page in the menu bar

Tags: html, css

How can I change the menu color when the page is selected?

Example:

> home faq contact_us

I want to show which page is selected in the menu bar. I'm using CSS but not sure how to go about this.

My CSS code:

```
.menu { 
    float: left;
    margin: 0px 0 0 0;
     width: 1000px;
     } 
    .menu li {  
     border-left: 1px solid #fff;
     float: left;
     line-height: 1em;
     text-align: center;} .menu li a {  color: #fff;
     display: block;
     font: 17px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
     padding: 0px 31px;     
     line-height:47px;
     text-decoration: none;
      } 
   .menu li a span {display:block; padding:0px 15px;} 
   .menu li a:hover, .menu  .active a{color:#fff;
    background:#ed1f26 url(images/menuleft.jpg) left top no-repeat;
    width:auto;  
   } 
    .menu li a:hover span, .menu .active a span
   {background: url(images/menuright.jpg) right top no-repeat;
    padding:0px 14px; 
    border:1px solid #b3c302;
  }
```

Comment: Do you hardcode your menu's or do you use translations?

Comment: i just add my css , that used in to active a page

Comment: did you use any menu tabs module for that stuff.

Comment: no i m using only html and css

Comment: @ruby:using the menu items in every page?

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you're writing the menu to each page (as seems to be the case from your comments) there's nothing stopping you from changing the background colour for the specific `<li>` related to that page.

Example below showing white background for current page (Home) or default colour for non-active pages.

```
<li style="background-color:rgb(255,255,255);">Home</li>
<li>FAQ</li>
<li>Contact Us</li>
```

Alternatively you could use some script and create tabs like I have done in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gstubbenhagen/zAbmA/

I would only recommend the tabs if you don't have too much content on each page as you don't want to make 1 very large page which takes forever to load on slower connections.

***NOTE:*** If using the tabs option the example provided uses a JQuery plugin, make sure you add the same tools if you are not going to re-code.