# nav menu highlighted the active page?

Tags: html, css

I have three selection in my nav menu. Portfolio, About, and Contact.
Here is the markup of it.

**HTML**

```
<div id="nav">
 <a class="homePage" href="/index/0-1">Portfolio</a>
 <a class="aboutPage" href="/index/0-2">About</a>
 <a class="contactPage" href="/index/0-3">Contact</a>
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#nav {
   text-align: center; 
   text-decoration: none; 
   margin-top: 20px; 
   padding-top: 31px;
}
#nav a {
   text-decoration: none; 
   color: #FFFFFF; 
   font-family: maven; 
   border-bottom: #FFFFFF 2px solid; 
   padding-bottom: 5px; 
   font-size:20px;
}
#nav a:hover {
   text-decoration: none; 
   color: #ff6464; 
   border-bottom: #ff6464 2px solid;
}
```

Now here is an example of what I'm wanting to do:

On homepage (which is portfolio), "portfolio" in the nav menu stays the color #ff6464 as long as your on that page. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767289/highlight-the-current-page-in-the-menu-bar?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

create a `.selected` class and apply it to the current page. Have it override the color into what you want.

**HTML**

```
<div id="nav">
 <!-- add a new class to portfolio/whatever the current page is -->
 <a class="homePage selected" href="/index/0-1">Portfolio</a>
 <a class="aboutPage" href="/index/0-2">About</a>
 <a class="contactPage" href="/index/0-3">Contact</a>
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#nav {text-align:center; text-decoration:none; margin-top:20px; padding-top: 31px;}
#nav a {text-decoration:none; color:#FFFFFF; font-family:maven; border-bottom:#FFFFFF 2px solid; padding-bottom:5px; font-size:20px;}
#nav a:hover {text-decoration:none; color: #ff6464; border-bottom: #ff6464 2px solid;}
#nav a.selected {color: #ff6464;} /* <---- new style! */
```

Comment: But that makes it highlighted no matter what? When I got to "about", "homepage" is still highlighted.

Comment: Yes. You need to now go and apply the "selected" class to the correct element for every page. You've tagged your question as `html` and `css` and also provided no more information other than that. I have no idea how you're serving these pages, no one does, so we can't help you any more than this. If you are using a templating system, then you'll need to dynamically set the class of the current page link. If you're using static HTML, then you'll need to manually go and set it for each page.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you assigned class to all pages here when there is no stylesheet applied for them here (I remove them here and pls ignore this if you have used them in other purposes). As ByteBlast and Jace has answered, you could assign a class for that active page. So your HTML could be:

```
<div id="nav">
   <a class="selected" href="/index/0-1">Portfolio</a>
   <a href="/index/0-2">About</a>
   <a href="/index/0-3">Contact</a>
</div>
```

Then your CSS would be (by removing unnecessary styles):

```
#nav {
   text-align: center; 
   margin-top: 20px; 
   padding-top: 31px;
}
#nav a {
   text-decoration: none; 
   color: #FFFFFF; 
   font-family: maven; 
   border-bottom: #FFFFFF 2px solid; 
   padding-bottom: 5px; 
   font-size:20px;
}
#nav a:hover {
   color: #ff6464; 
   border-bottom: #ff6464 2px solid;
}
#nav a.selected {
   color: #ff6464;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

In your Portfolio page:

```
<div id="nav">
   <a class="selected" href="/index/0-1">Portfolio</a>
   <a href="/index/0-2">About</a>
   <a href="/index/0-3">Contact</a>
</div>
```

In your About page

```
<div id="nav">
   <a href="/index/0-1">Portfolio</a>
   <a class="selected" href="/index/0-2">About</a>
   <a href="/index/0-3">Contact</a>
</div>
```

and in your Contact page

```
<div id="nav">
   <a href="/index/0-1">Portfolio</a>
   <a href="/index/0-2">About</a>
   <a class="selected" href="/index/0-3">Contact</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, but when they go to the about Page, Portfolio will still be highlighted.

Comment: hmmm, it's kindaeasy. On page Portfolio you assigned the class "selected" and in the page About, you assign the class "selected" and remove the class "selected from the portfolio. See my update.