# header menu attributes (Div, image and text ) change value on active page

Tags: html, css

I have a menu  which consist of 4 div, each div contains an image and a text. 
I want to indicate to the user which page is actvie by changing (http://jsfiddle.net/celiostat/mnQ9g/1/) :

- the image colour (obviously i have the images on two colours)
- the text color
- the div color background

I have to say due to the fact of the changes on all 3 elements I couldn't find a answer !

HTML :

```
    <nav class="fouritemselector_menubar container">
    <div class="item_unselected">
        <img class="item_icon_in_menubar" src="http://files.softicons.com/download/system-icons/rhon-icons-by-harenome-razanajato/png/512x512/folder-blue.png">
        <span class="item_text_in_menubar">all</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item_unselected">
        <img class="item_icon_in_menubar" src="http://www.mouserunner.com/Icons/Orb_Blue_Preview_Icon.png">
        <span class="item_text_in_menubar">story</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item_unselected">
        <img class="item_icon_in_menubar" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/kyo-tux/aeon/256/Misc-Buddy-Blue-icon.png">
        <span class="item_text_in_menubar">dish</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item_unselected">
        <img class="item_icon_in_menubar" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/hopstarter/scrap/256/Folder-Closed-Blue-icon.png">
        <span class="item_text_in_menubar">restaurant</span>
    </div>
</nav>
```

CSS :

```
.fouritemselector_menubar
{
height: auto;
display: table;
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-bottom: :10px;
}


.item_unselected
{
height: auto;
background-color: gray;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
width: 25%;
box-sizing: border-box;
border-right: 1px solid #ECF0F1;
}

.item_icon_in_menubar
{
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
float: none;
position: relative;
overflow: auto;
width: 25%;
max-width: 60px;
padding-top: 12px;
}

.item_text_in_menubar
{
display: table;
margin: auto;
float: none;
font-size: 90%;
font-family: "Montserrat";
padding-top: 4px;
padding-bottom: 4px;
color: #AFAFAF;
 }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Highlight the current page in the menu bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767289/highlight-the-current-page-in-the-menu-bar)

Comment: either paulie's link, or instead of divs use restyled radio boxes and style them on `:active`

Comment: thanks, i am looking as fiddle at the moment from the conversation pointed by Paulie, trying to get my head around it ! the image component will add another layer of complexity i guess ..